# How to use Connected Thread in multiple activites

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets, bluetooth

I am newbie in Android. First I've written an application which connects to another device via Bluetooth, then sends and receives data, using socket and connected thread. While using one activity everything works great, I receive data using handler.
Then I started to make an application with multiple activities, so I made a special class for socket connection and connected thread. I send data normally from any activity,  but I don't know how to receive an answer (how to make a handler in many activities, or what alternative to use). Could you possibly help me and write this lines of code, that I should add.

Thanks.

Here is my thread:

```
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
          mmSocket = socket;
          InputStream tmpIn = null;
          OutputStream tmpOut = null;

          try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
          }
          catch (IOException e) {}

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
          }
          public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
            int bytes;
            while(true) {
              try {
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) buffer;
                String strIncom = new String(readBuf, 0, bytes);

                  // Here I need some method to send data to activity
              }
              catch (IOException e) {
                  break;
                }
              }
            }

              public void write(String message) { 
            byte[] msgBuffer = message.getBytes();
                try {
                    mmOutStream.write(msgBuffer);
                } catch (IOException e) {

                  }

          }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Well, one thing you can do is the use of an `Interface`,

for example:

```
public class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
// You declare your interface in the Class body
    public static interface CallBackListener
    {
        public void onReceived(String msg);
    }

   private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
   private final InputStream mmInStream;
   private final OutputStream mmOutStream;
   private CallBackListener listener = null;

// then, those who want to use this class must implement 
// this interface
   public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket, CallBackListener aListener) 
   {        
         this.listener = aListener;
         ...
```

And in the run method of the thread you do like this:

```
// Here I need some method to send data to activity
if (listener != null)
{
   listener.onReceived(strIncom);
}
```

And when you create the class, do like this:

```
BluetoothSocket socket = null;
/*
* Create the BlueToothSocket here
   BluetoothSocket socket = new BluetoothSocket(...);
*/

ConnectedThread conThread = new ConnectedThread(socket, new ConnectedThread.CallBackListener()
{
   @Override
   public void onReceived(String msg)
   {
    // here you'll receive the string msg
    // keep in mind that you receive this call 
    // in the ConnectedThread's context, not the UI thread
   }
});
```