# Calling a method form a different thread in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, bluetooth

How do you use a method which is defined in another thread(not main) and in in a different class?Direct example is there is a ConnectedThread class in a bluetooth tutorial onAndroidDev 
and in that class there is a write() method which is used to put something on a output stream of bluetooth.How can i use that method in the main  activiy because i want to send an information by pressing a button?

```
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
        // member streams are final
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) { }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream
        int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
                mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
    public void write(byte[] bytes) { //how do i use this method in the ui(main) activity?
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(bytes);
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }

    /* Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22325905/how-to-use-connected-thread-in-multiple-activites ?

Comment: Your question is a bit confused-  functions are not defined in Threads.  They're defined in classes.  Any function can be called on any thread, although doing so may cause problems elsewhere in the system it is legal Java.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the method you are trying to access from another class is a public method.

Answer (score 0):

In this example the **main activity** calls a fragmentActivity and shows the fragment in the **layout main activity**. What you have to do is create a new button in the *layout fragmentActivity* and instantiate within the *onViewCreated*. After the button initializes the event within `setupChat ()` method sending the `sendMessage ("yourMessage")` your information through parameter. Everything inside the fragment activity.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using an `eventbus` such as EventBus or Otto. If you are changing the UI, you will need to register for the event and then run your code on the main thread with something like `Activity.runOnUIThread(){}`